# How can I emulate a sudo shell with the respective environment variables set when using "sudo su -c "<command>"?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, bashrc

I would like to run a sudo command in one line, but also have this command be run as a sudo user with all the respective environment variables instantiated (essentially run `exec zsh` before anything).

```
sudo su -c "echo $HOME"
```

returns my user-home directory instead of `/root`, and

```
sudo su -l -c "exec zsh && echo $HOME"
```

simply sets my shell to root without running the command. I need this because I am creating another program on a different computer that is supposed to be able to remotely run singular commands as both a regular and root user on this computer using [python paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/).

Comment: `sudo su -c "echo $HOME"` returns the user's home directory because double quotes permit the interactive shell to expand `$HOME` before `su -c` is invoked.

Comment: is there a way to delay the invocation of $HOME in this case?

Comment: Yes - single quotes: `sudo su -c 'echo $HOME'`